# Redirect old page to new html page using .htaccess

Tags: php, html

We have a static HTML website having MicrosoftDynamics.html page recently we changed to MicrosoftDynamicsNav.html.

But when we searched in google the page URL is showing old one, If we clicked the link we are getting 404 error.

So we decided to write the 404-page redirects rules from the **.htaccess**  file. But it's not working for me. For these, I have tried below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RedirectMatch 404 /MicrosoftDynamics.html /MicrosoftDynamicsNav.html
</IfModule>
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of this is not Magento related question.

Comment: @ChiragPatel, It is valid to question I think, any language we have to do if we get 404. Of course, Magento has URL Rewrites.

Comment: Okay so for that you have to modify your question as per Magento StackExchange network or you can ask a question in https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @ChiragPatel Okay thank you.